# How can I limit number of triangles in delaunay triangulation?

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a polyhedron which its vertices are specified. To this end, I use `delaunayTriangulation` command, but there is a problem and that is high number of triangular faces.So, is there any way to limitation of number of triangular faces? For example,I would like to generate a polyhedron by 8 triangular faces.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of how a [Delaunay triangle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html) is created is that it is using the halfway point, on a lines to the nearest proximal neighbours, to nearest surrounding points to define the edge of the triangle surrounding a point.  At its most basic to create 8 triangles you would need 8 points; you would have to accommodate the edge effects but you would have 8 facets or triangles. If you are specifying the vertices of the triangles instead of the central points you will probably get a lot more triangles that required and also may not be getting an appropriate depiction of the analysis you are looking for. Matlab has the capacity to control edge effects in a 2d depiction. HTH, Mark